# Stop file to be downloaded from direct link

Tags: asp.net, download

I have this class in an asp web form and I am trying to allow the download from users only if they have the password and the link to the file that is sent to them.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Get the filename from the link and the password entered by the user
        string savefilename = Request.QueryString["file"];
        string password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

        //Make sure that the password maches for the requested file
        if (BLCustomerFile.IsUserAuthenticated(savefilename, password))
        {
            //Check if the file still exists on the server
            string filename = savefilename.Substring(32);
            string fileserverpath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + savefilename);
            if (File.Exists(fileserverpath))
            {
                //Response back with the file -- file download
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileserverpath);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
                Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "File No longer exists on the server.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "You are not authorized to download this file.";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Some error occurred. Please try again later.";
    }
}
```

The problem: The link I give to the user is url+filename+extension, when it is pasted in the browser the file get downloaded immediately. Is there a way to stop this to happen and to force the above code to execute and therefore to check the password?

I know I can change the logic of the system but if there is a solution I would leave it in this way to avoid to have to give to the customer url, file name and password separately.

Comment: Use a [handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) to provide the file to the client. Move the original file somewhere where it won't be served to anyone. Then force everything to access the file via the handler (where you can do authorization checks).

Comment: @mason, thanks. That sound a solution to explore.